Comparing different timepoints of measurements (1,2,3,4) for a group of individuals who survived vs. not survived
In most cases we have a time series based measurement (CD8T) for a group of individuals who survived or not survived (Survival) from a disease (repeated measurements). The timepoint based measurements are partially incomplete beacuse of missing data thats why sometimes the series is not complete (Time_Point). We would like to know whether a change in the composition (CD8T) over time had an effect on the survival. Further, we would like to correct for age and gender. What model would you suggest?
Any help and design, contrast and code to apply in R is highly appreciated.


There seems to be something unusual in how the data is coded. Take for example Sample-240. Why are there 3 no's in the Survival column? Presumably the individual wouldn't have reached time points 2 and 3 if they haven't survived up to time point 1. Also not sure about the precision in measurements such as 7.47E-19.
